# Are NMAMapRoutes tappable?

Tags: here-api

I have a map route shown in my map view, and I've set up the delegate and delegate methods as per the instructions. But when I tap on the route, nothing happens. However, the delegate method fires fine when I tap on a map circle.

Are routes not tappable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **NMAMapRoutes** is tappable.

Follow below code, to solved your issue

```
-(void)mapView:(NMAMapView *)mapView didSelectObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{
  for (int j=0; j<[objects count]; j++) {

      if ([[objects objectAtIndex:j] isKindOfClass:[NMAMapRoute class]])  {
        NSLog(@"NMAMapRoute:");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Does it work with Swift? I'm using Swift and it doesn't seem to be working. I can detect taps on Map Circles though.